# How to redirect stdout to a file in Cloud Run?

Tags: python, stdout, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-logging

I have a python program that runs a script and this script writes its output to stdout, which I need to use later in my program.
Since this script is in binary and I can't change it's source code, so I redirected the output of my script to a file, then I read the file as below :

```
os.popen("./my_script > test.txt")

with open("test.txt", "r") as f:
    output = " ".join(f.readlines())

print(f"I can process my output : {output} here")
```

The program works great, until I try to deploy it to Cloud Run. The output is not redirected to a file, but automatically redirected to Cloud Logging, and I can no longer use it in my program.

Comment: May be your script is writing to stderr? try `> test.txt 2>&1`

Comment: hm it seems to work, which I don't understand why.
It was running well on my local docker container but not on cloud run, which means the output goes on stdout on my computer, but on stderr on Cloud run ?

Comment: On Cloud Run, stdout and stderr are handled differently than Docker. You do not show what your script does. A script that is binary is **not** a script. Make sure you know what that program does. Some programs directly write to stderr instead of stdout. You should only be writing to `/tmp` e.g. `os.popen("./my_script > /tmp/test.txt 2>&1")`.  I recommend that you control stdout and stdout programmatically and not by redirection to a file.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments by @John Hanley On Cloud Run, `stdout` and `stderr` are handled differently than Docker.

You do not show what your script does. A script that is binary is not a script.

Make sure you know what that program does. Some programs directly write to `stderr` instead of `stdout`. You should only be writing to `/tmp` e.g. `os.popen("./my_script > /tmp/test.txt 2>&1")`.

I recommend that you control `stdout` and `stdout` programmatically and not by redirection to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood CloudRun runs your application in container. All prints to `stdout` and `stderr` in containers are forwarded to Cloud Logging by a logging agent that CloudRun runs implicitly. But it is not like it is "redirected" or "captured". The agent reads the output from the file where CRI stores it. (Everything is a file in Linux).

It is my understanding that `os.popen()` opens a process to execute the command. This is generally considered anti-pattern when running application in a container.

Given the `os.popen()` eventually calls to `subprocess.Popen()` you can rewrite your code to use [subprocess.Popen()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) directly and substitute your own streams for `stdout` and `stderr`